# Increasing sas memory/memsize

Tags: memory, memory-management, sas

Hi have a dataset wih about 6000 obs and 250 variables. I am trying to run a mixed model in sas using proc mixed but I keep getting "Error:the sas system stopped processing this step because of insufficient memory" . I tried the cornell university's way- http://www.ciser.cornell.edu/FAQ/SAS/MemoryAllocation.shtm , but its not working as under "properties", its not letting me modify "target".

I tried,
Proc options option=memsize 4G;
Run;

but obviously there is something wrong with the code and I keep getting error. I want to increase the memory assigned by sas which right now is 2gb.
I am using the sas provided by my school, so I am guessing its a student version. Don't know if that has anything to do with this memory error.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with changing the memsize to max or something bigger than 2gb.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MEMSIZE is an option that [can be set in "configuration file, SAS invocation"](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0srij4mcdpzv2n1vtphltb00xjw.htm).

Here's how you set it: [Syntax for System Options in the SAS Invocation or SAS Configuration File](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0drw76qo0gig2n1kcoliekh605k.htm):

- When running:`sas.exe -memsize 4G`
- Or by putting `-memsize 4G` in your sasv9.cfg (there's a [complicated search algorithm for sasv9.cfg files](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0bmj7wjme32ayn1h4wim7trkhp6.htm#p1f8pahglb6jz0n18i9bd3xxl84r), but you can put one in the directory you invoke SAS from).

If you're using SAS EG or SAS EM in client-server environment, that's something your administrator must configure.

PS. missed the instructions in your link -- that's what you should do. You could just run the necessary command from Start -> Run (or create a new shortcut) if you have trouble with modifying the existing one.

Comment: Thanks! I think its working now. I went to Start -> Run -> sas.exe -memsize 4G 
..I am not getting the error anymore.