# MCMC taking forever to run in SAS

Tags: sas, mcmc

Suppose I have a regression where the response variable is sales, and I have various drivers of sales as the independent variables. I want to build a model using MCMC but I am unsure if it is even possible ( I am running in SAS). See below for a simplified model structure (there are many more variables and random interactions in the production model):

Yij=β0+β1TVX1ij+γ(TV×dma)i+εi

For the model above, I have one main effect for TV represented by β1 and a random interaction between DMA (there are 210 DMAS in the US) and TV which is represented by gamma. I have priors for all my parameters and when I run MCMC in SAS, it takes hours to run. Can MCMC handle 210 random interaction for the random term? I am using MCMC because I want to utilize the prior knowledge from previous modeling rounds but it makes no sense if it takes forever to run.

```
proc mcmc data=modeldbsubset outpost=postout thin=1000 nmc=20000 seed=7893

         monitor=(b0 b1);
  ods select PostSummaries PostIntervals tadpanel;
  parms b0 0 b1 0;
  parms s2 1 ;
  parms s2g 1;
  prior b: ~ normal(0, var = 10000);
  prior s2: ~ igamma(0.001, scale = 1000);
    random gamma ~ normal(0, var=s2g) subject = dmanum monitor = (gamma) namesuffix = position;


  mu = b0 + b1*TV + gamma;

  model Y ~ normal(mu, var = s2);
```

Comment: 1. How many observations do you have? 2. Does it ever finish? 3. Have you modified any of the memory settings?

Comment: @Reeza The data set has 210 regions x 100 weeks of data so about 21,000 rows of data. I have the sales data and TV spend for each row. Ultimately, I want to estimate a main effect and DMA effect for TV, so that the final coeffcient for each DMA would be TV Main Effect + DMA TV Random Effect. So there would be 210 gammas (random effects) to be estimated, as well as one β0 and one β1 to be estimated. Does that make sense? The problem is that it takes a very long time for one iteration of MCMC to run? Is that due to estimating all the gammas? I never modified the memory settings.

Comment: Try changing your memory settings first. Which version of SAS are you using? You have to change the config file which is kind of a pain, and if you don't have admin rights to the machine you can't do it.

Comment: @Reeza I am using SAS 9.4 TS Level 1M3. Maybe thats the issue? I also have access to SAS EG and SAS Grid so I may try it there. It'sa company laptop so I may not have the admin rights.

Comment: Yeah, if you have access to grid, definitely try it there. Shouldn't take too long. Otherwise here's how you can modify your settings. I think the default is 2GB which is fairly small in todays world. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038194/increasing-sas-memory-memsize

Comment: How much control do you have over changing the proposal distribution? I am assuming it is Metropolis that you are running? Can you get a metric on the percentage of rejected samples (you should aim for a step size that gets you about 60% accepted)?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t use SAS, but it’s no surprise this scale of model would fail miserably with the default random walk Metropolis they use, which initializes with an identity cov matrix for the proposal distribution. [The documentation on scale tuning](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mcmc_sect022.htm) says you can tune to a MAP estimate of cov (this is what PyMC3 does by default), so maybe try starting there. However, the docs also say doing this will then use the MAP for parameter initialization, which is a bad idea since MAP is usually not in the typical set at high dimensions.

In the end, I expect you’ll need to do a lot of tuning specific to your data to really get it running cleanly, and unfortunately that’s just part of the art.

Alternatively, you might be better off picking up a more advanced MCMC sampling framework that implements HMC/NUTS, such as Stan or PyMC3 or Edward.  There are even some high-level packages, like RStanArm, specifically for Bayesian regression modeling, but which keep the lower level MCMC stuff in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am relatively new to MCMC and took a course on it in SAS. Are you saying Python/Stan are better tools for the modeling problem compared to SAS? I wouldn't know how to tune the paramaters in SAS to get MCMC to run more efficiently and feel it may be too much guess and check work.

Comment: @lord12 IMHO, yes. Stan really pushed the frontier on MCMC sampling in recent years by implementing versions of more robust and efficient samplers. They still aren't guaranteed to work on first try, but the scale of models it can handle is much larger. PyMC3 has mostly caught up with Stan, and I prefer it for having a single language and out-of-the-box support for discrete sampling. Edward/Tensorflow Probability is likely the future, but it's a steeper learning curve. All MCMC has a learning curve to do correctly, so expect to read manuals no matter what. Stan also has great docs.